# R data spread only in lines

Tags: r

I have a file with data in this way:

Name: abcdef
Value:40
Id:34
Size: 1000

Name: xyz
Value:4
Id:765
Size: 5561000

Name: qwerty
Value:0
Id:4
Size: 1000

But I would something like this:

| Name    | Value | Id     | Size            |
| abcdef   | 40         | 34    | 1000          |
| xyz         | 4            | 765 | 5561000 |
| qwerty   | 0            | 4       | 1000          |

It's possible do that with R standard commands?

Comment: Yes. Is there anything you've already tried yourself?

Comment: I seem to remember that the 'splitstackshape' package has facilities for reading 'attribute:value' data. Paging @AnandaMahto

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the imagined function in splitstackshape, nor could I find the duplicate question on SO that I also imagined I had seen using "attribute value" or "label value" as search terms, but I can offer a solution based on `scan`'s ability to handle multi-line data and `sub` to trim out the excess text. You can obviously remove the dangling column:

```
inp <- scan(text=txt, what=list("n", "v", "i", "s", "blank"),sep="\n")
Read 3 records
names(inp) <- lapply(inp , function(col) sub("\\:.+","",col[1]) )
inp <- data.frame( lapply(inp, function(col) sub(".+\\:[ ]{0,1}","",col) ) )
> inp
    Name Value  Id    Size c............
1 abcdef    40  34    1000              
2    xyz     4 765 5561000              
3 qwerty     0   4    1000
```

This will require that the data be very regular. Each section needs to be 5 lines and the order inside a section of the values needs to be constant, although blank values should be handled correctly.

Data used:

```
txt <- "Name: abcdef
Value:40
Id:34
Size: 1000

Name: xyz
Value:4
Id:765
Size: 5561000

Name: qwerty
Value:0
Id:4
Size: 1000
"
```